# Как добавить ряд в начало GridPane и сдвинуть вниз остальные элементы

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

Как добавить ряд в начало GridPane и так, что бы следующие элементы сдвигались вниз, т.е. меняли свой индекс на +1?
Если просто добавлять ряд в начало `gridPane.getRowConstraints().add(0, rowConstraints);`, то заменяется ряд который был на 0 индексе. 
Спасибо за любую наводку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В описании написано, что элемент будет вправо на 1. Но этого не происходит. Элементы наслаиваются в строке (колонке) с одинаковыми индексами.

Можно двигать элементы самостоятельно, если это необходимо. Можно задавать элементам в ячейках стили, гарантирующие наличие отступов между элементами в одной колонке или строке.

```
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Move Label");
        btn.setMinWidth(100);

        GridPane root = new GridPane();
        root.add(btn,0,0);

        Label label = new Label("Hello!");
        label.setMinWidth(100);

        RowConstraints rowConstraints = new RowConstraints(100,100,100);
        ColumnConstraints columnConstraints = new ColumnConstraints(100,100,100);

        root.getRowConstraints().add(0, rowConstraints);
        root.getColumnConstraints().add(0, columnConstraints);

        root.add(label, 0, 0);

        btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            root.getChildren().remove(label);
            root.add(label, 1, 0);
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
```

В [примере](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JavaFX/0340__JavaFX_GridPane.htm) есть такие действия:

```
GridPane gridpane = new GridPane();
gridpane.setPadding(new Insets(5));
gridpane.setHgap(5);
gridpane.setVgap(5);
ColumnConstraints column1 = new ColumnConstraints(100);
ColumnConstraints column2 = new ColumnConstraints(50, 150, 300);
column2.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
gridpane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(column1, column2);
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую ближе к вечеру - отпишусь!

Comment: Мне кажется, что было бы намного проще использовать контейнер типа VBox, т.к. он служит для этих целей.

Comment: Хорошее замечание. Возможно, для целей jessez могут подойти другие контейнеры. С их (почти?) полным списком можно ознакомиться здесь: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/ , или скачав Gluon (JavaFX SceneBuilder) http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/.

Comment: @DimXenon а Gluon и JavaFX Scene builder чем нибудь отличаются или это одно и то же?

Comment: Одно и то же. Просто Gluon - продолжение "заброшенного" (почему?) проекта Oracle.

Comment: @AndrewBystrov спасибо, попробую VBox использовать